# How to append input value

Tags: jquery

This snippet appear `deneme` text but I want to appear input value for every click to the `button.Simply` I want to make to do list. How can I do it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("p").append("deneme");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input> deneme </input> <button> eryjhbhh </button>
<p>fdjd</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    const val = $(this).prev().val().trim(); // or $("#inputFieldId").val().trim()
    if (val !== "") $("ul").append(`<li>${val}</li>`);  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input /> <button>Add</button>
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check for input value before appending otherwise it will append empty li as well.
Eg:

```
if($("#inputFieldId").val() !=='') {
  $("ul").append(`<li>${$("#inputFieldId").val()}</li>`);
}
```

Comment: Your code absolutely answered the actual question. I just suggested to add check to avoid empty values. BTW i am new here and trying to learn how things work here.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).